# tf::MessageFilter, laser callback in gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, message-filters, gmapping, message-filter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ,

i am working with offlinedata to build gridmap using gmapping in ros.

My query is why `SlamGMapping::laserCallback` is not getting called everytime it recieves a `sensor_msgs::LaserScan`.

For mycase  when i am publishing 107 `sensor_msgs::LaserScan` and 107 `/tf` and 107 `nav_msgs::Odometry` messages `SlamGMapping::laserCallback` is called only for 6 times for messages 0,1,18,65,78,99.

[tf::MessageFilter](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/groovy-devel/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp#L228)

```
  scan_filter_sub_ = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(node_, "scan", 5);
  scan_filter_ = new tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(*scan_filter_sub_, tf_, odom_frame_, 5);
  scan_filter_->registerCallback(boost::bind(&SlamGMapping::laserCallback, this, _1));
```

[SlamGMapping::laserCallback](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/groovy-devel/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp#L476)

```
void SlamGMapping::laserCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan)
{
  laser_count_++;
  ROS_INFO("laser_count_= %d  sequence =%d",laser_count_,scan->header.seq);
```

why `SlamGMapping::laserCallback` is not getting called everytime it recieves `sensor_msgs::LaserScan` and `/tf`.

How to make all the scans being processed.

-- Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126791/tf::messagefilter,-laser-callback-in-gmapping/) by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3034 on 2014-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gmapping does not use every laserscan, as this would cause the graph to get huge and also probably run quite slowly. Instead, it uses laserscans that are "sufficiently far apart", based on three parameters:

- linearUpdate
- angularUpdate
- temporalUpdate (usually not used)

The parameters and their defaults are described on the wiki page: http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-02-06**:
@fergs i am using  settings  "linearUpdate" ="0.5"( 50 cm) and "angularUpdate"="0.052"(3 degrees)  "temporalUpdate"="-1.0"( all scans) but checking these settings is in processscan which is called from addscan which is from laser call back. I doubt i need to sync odom->base tf with laserscan.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-02-06**:
I'm not familiar with the interior of the code base, but, -1.0 for a temporalUpdate does not mean "all scans", rather it means that you never trigger based on temporal updates, thus only based on x/angular movement (if you never moved, you would never update).